# where would report generation code go . 

Tags: c#, winforms, projects-and-solutions

I have a visual studio solution with the following projects:

1. UI
2. DataAccess
3. BusiessLogic
4. BusinessObjects

I now have a bunch of code that generates reports that are sent out via email or saved as csv files.

These ReportGenerators classes take in business objects and output either files or strings.

which project would you put them in?  I am leaning toward an answer but wanted to see what others thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a separate reporting project. It doesn't belong in the UI (I assume they run in the background) - it is effectively a 'reporting logic' layer.

If you think about how you might want to support reportng, you may want a backend service but you might want to expose the data via a web service as well in the future. If you need to provide users a front-end reporting facility you plug into the reporting logic as you would a normal UI -> Logic -> Data Access architecture.

Also, if you separate your reporting code out you are then free to extract it to a dedicated reporting tier in the future.

Comment: in that case, why not put into business logic

Comment: why clutter application logic with reporting logic? The term 'three tiered architecture' doesn't literally mean three physical tiers or projects. ultimately it is up to you, but my general rule is distinct functional areas go in their own projects.

Answer (score 0):

A agree with manwood's post - you should build them as reports (put a sproc behind the reports if necessary) for the following reasons:

- You can run the reports and display
  them through the ReportViewer
  control.  This is fairly
  straightforward to do.
- You (and more importantly other people
  supporting the application) can
  extend the application with more
  reports without having to release
  another build of the application.  This is quite a useful feature if you don't want to be tied to supporting the application.
- You can publish the reports through
  reporting services as well.
- You get all the data export options
  of reporting services (Excel, csv,
  pdf etc.) with the Reporting
  Services framework.